# Localized date format in tooltip

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

In my chart I'm displaying revenue data on a date axis by day. I would like to show the date in the tooltip formatted by locale setting, i.e.
* en-us: 2019-03-19
* de DE: 19.03.2019

I created a codepen inspired by the amcharts example here: https://codepen.io/Me12345678/pen/vPorre

When I specify a locale, the tooltip is still showing the en-US format:

```
chart.language.locale = am4lang_de_DE;
```

I can format the date in the tooltip text, but then the format is static and won't change with the locale:

```
series.tooltipText = `{dateX.formatDate("dd MMM yyyy")}: [b]{valueY}[/]`;
```

Is there any way to specify an abstract format like "date without time" or "date with time" or "month only", so that amcharts displays it according to the locale setting?

Thanks for reading :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this **formatDate(\"dd.MM.YYYY\")**

```
series.tooltipText = "[bold]{date.formatDate(\"dd.MM.YYYY\")}[/] \n + [bold]{valueY}[/]";
```